# How to get 5 last record in the sqlite db in android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Since the db does not have create date and some ordering field (but in my observation the last row is the latest record),

so how can i get the five last record in some condition e.g.
five record that their schoolid == 1?

Thanks

```
public Cursor select()
{
    String orderBy = FIELD_pubKey+" DESC";
    Cursor cursor = iReadDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, orderBy);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: You don't have a row id?

Comment: order by auto generated id, get 5 from cursor or select only five

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as a last record or a first or a 42nd.

Which records appears last in the result of a query is dependent on the query plan, or an Explicit order by if you add one.

Select * From Table Where ...
The rows will be returned in whatever order the engine considers suitable at the time. 
If you need them in specific order, then add an order by clause to the query, anything else is asking for it.

Something like

```
Select * From Table Order by SomeColumn desc limit 5
```

will do what you require.

Now what column you need to order by I've no idea, but you need one that will do the job, assuming automatic primary key, but note it is possible to mess with that.

Comment: PS an index (there will be one already for the key(s) on the column(s) you are ordering by will give you a significant improvement in performance.